# Prove nonsquare $111...161 = (10^k-1)/9+50$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

My question states: Prove that the number $\underbrace{11\cdots1}_{n\text{ times}}61$ (written in base $10$) is not a perfect square.

I've done somewhat similar problems with $\underbrace{11\cdots1}_{n\text{ times}}$ using the fact a odd perfect square is of the equivalent to $1\pmod{8}$. But this fact does not apply to this problem. I am stuck and would appreciate any hints?

Comment: Your title says prime, your question refers to squares.  Which is it?

Comment: I modified your question title, please review and [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2542121/edit) if it does not align with your intended question.

Comment: In case you're wondering about primes,  $11161$, $11111161$, $111111111111111161$, $11111111111111111111111111111111111161$ are prime.  Maybe infinitely many more, though of course we're nowhere near being able to prove that.

Comment: **Hint:** $\,n = (10^k\!-\!1)/9+ 50.\,$ Note square $n\!\iff $square $9n = \color{#c00}{10^k}\!+\!449.\, $ Test the latter $\!\bmod p\,$ by choosing $p$ so that $10^k\bmod p$ [has *few* values (e.g. $\pm 1)\ \ $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2542121/prove-111-161-is-not-a-square#comment9750371_2542156)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be approached with a method similar to the one you described for $11\cdots 11,$ but it's a little more complex.

We can split this up into two cases, where the number of digits is either even or odd.

If the number of digits is even, then we can express the number as $11\cdot 10^{2k}+11\cdot 10^{2k-2}+\cdots+1100+61.$  This value is congruent to $6\pmod{11}.$

If the numbers of digits is odd, then we can express the number as $11\cdot 10^{2k+1}+11\cdot 10^{2k-1} + \cdots + 11000+161.$  This is congruent to $7\pmod{11}.$

Just as we know that all squares are either $0$ or $1\pmod{8},$ we also know that all squares are either $0,1,3,4,5,$ or $9\pmod {11}.$  Therefore, $11\cdots 61$ cannot be a perfect square because it is always either $6$ or $7\pmod{11}.$

Comment: Simpler: $\,n = (10^k\!-\!1)/9+ 50.\,$ square $n\!\iff $square $9n = \color{#c00}{10^k}\!+\!449\equiv \color{#c00}{\pm1}\!+\!9\pmod{\!11}\ \ $

Answer (score 3):

I suppose that what you are trying to say is $1\cdots 161$ is not a *square* (rather than prime).

Hint: modulo 11. There are two cases: when the number of digits is even and when the number of digits is odd.